# UIButton in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I need to add a gesture (move, rotate, scale) to a `UIButton`. 
I created the button in code, but I don't know how to use it. 
If the button is touched I want to move, scale or rotate.
Here is my code:

```
-(void)addButton{
UIScrollView *scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)]; 
scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;
scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[self.view addSubview:scrollview];
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width,1000.0);
buttonImage1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
buttonImage1.frame = CGRectMake(100, 20, 100, 100);
UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                             [NSURL URLWithString:adres1]]];
[buttonImage1 setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[scrollview addSubview:buttonImage1];


buttonImage2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
buttonImage2.frame = CGRectMake(100, 180, 150, 150);
UIImage *btnImage2 = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                             [NSURL URLWithString:adres2]]];
[buttonImage2 setImage:btnImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[scrollview addSubview:buttonImage2];
buttonImage3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
buttonImage3.frame = CGRectMake(100, 450, 194, 146);
UIImage *btnImage3 = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                             [NSURL URLWithString:adres3]]];
[buttonImage3 setImage:btnImage3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[scrollview addSubview:buttonImage3];
}

-(void) move 
{

}
```

Comment: you should at least try to add the gesture recognizer yourself.

Comment: i am new in xcode. i didn't know how, can you show me example

Comment: you don't bother to read documentation, do you?

Comment: i was try but i do not understand to many word in english because i from poland

Comment: I am also not native english speaking. But most programming languages and all important documentation are in english. You will have to work with it.

Comment: yes i know, i lern english every day, but it is to slowly to do this app i do app for my friend and i must do this quicker

Comment: sorry man, but we are really not here to to your job. we can provide help with faulty code, but the base must come from you.

Comment: To `move`, `rotate` and `scale` something on-screen look into the `setTransform`, `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation`, `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` and `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` methods.  Do an internet search and example code is readily available. Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

> I need to add a gesture (move, rotate, scale) to a UIButton.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean about adding a gesture. Right now, your buttons aren't set up to do anything at all.

> I created the button in code, but I don't know how to use it.

You need to add a target and action to your button. When a button is tapped, it sends an *action* message to some other object, which is its *target*. To set up a button, you need to add a target and action using the `-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method inherited from `UIControl`. If you want the button to send a `move` message to the same object that's creating the button, you'd change your `addButton` method to include this:

```
[buttonImage1 addTarget:self action:@selector(move) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: yes now didn't do anything, i need move, scale, rotate my button. thank for help with add selector